# Javascript,Jquery does not work when i change the tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jira

I apply the below script to add color to the comments I add in my application (JIRA).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".activity-comment:even").css("background-color","#6699FF"); 
    $(".activity-comment:odd").css("background-color","#B2CCFF"); 
});
```

[comments http://i.minus.com/jFoE7kcaTqdrp.JPG](http://i.minus.com/jFoE7kcaTqdrp.JPG)

After applying the script the comments appear as above , however the script does not work when i move to other tabs (i.e. Worklog , History) or i add a new comment. I need to refresh the page for the script to execute .

Can someone please help me how i can permanently set the colors ?

Note : I am applying the javascript on the application announcement banner this makes the script run on every page of the application , I can make changes to the source files.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: you mean an additional CSS file which will do this ? can you please provide an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this thing in 2 ways:

**1- By using CSS**: In your css file just add following lines of code:

```
.activity-comment:even{
    background-color: #6699FF;
}
.activity-comment:odd{
    background-color: #B2CCFF;
}
```

**2- By Jquery**: In this case use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function of jquery to achieve style on dynamic added comments. Like get the id of comment submit button (suppose: comment_add) , and then:

```
$("#comment_add").live('click',function(){
    $(".activity-comment:even").css("background-color","#6699FF"); 
    $(".activity-comment:odd").css("background-color","#B2CCFF");
});
```

I think it will help you.

Comment: `live` is deprecated, use `on` instead

Comment: @Workonphp , I want to go with CSS as there are many ways of adding a comment and user can toggle between the tabs . I tried your CSS solution but unfortunately it is not working . Can you please help . Thanks

Comment: Mizan: Can u try  it with jquery also, I think it will not be a big deal.

Comment: jquery is also not working , when i add a comment there are some ajax request sent I used firebug to find this .

Comment: I was able to resolve this by using the setInterval() where i execute the css ever 100ms .